# How can you run an Excel macro through a schedule task

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a macro in an Excel spreadsheet through a schedule task.
I've defined the job as below:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10\EXCEL.EXE" ""

The problem is that when the job starts Excel displays a pop-up and asks if we want to disable/enable the macros, which blocks the execution of the job.

How can I run this macro without having to manually click on enable macro?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771185/how-to-set-recurring-schedule-for-xlsm-file-using-windows-task-scheduler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write a short vbscript which launches Excel, loads your workbook and uses Application.Run to run the macro. Have your scheduled task run the vbscript.

Eg: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=302970

Comment: +1 Best approach. It many be worth recoding the macro inside the vbs to ensure the code runs, ie defeat the enabling macros issues.

Comment: The script appears to work but doesn't prevent the "Enable Macros" prompt. I think it may have something to do with an installed corporate security policy at my workplace?

Answer (score 3):

*You do not specify what version of Excel or what version of Windows (or Macintosh) so I will specify that I am using Excel 2010 from Office 32-bit on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit...*

---

**If you want to keep your workbook open and run code at a specified time, later on, then try this..**

Insert a new code module to your project -or- use one that you already have in your project.

Create a scheduler subroutine as shown below:

```
Sub Scheduler()

'-- RUNS SUB(S) (OR FUNCTIONS) AT TIME SCHEDULED.

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("11:46:40"), "TheScheduledSub"

End Sub
```

Create a subroutine (or function) that you want to run.  Here is one for this example:

```
Sub TheScheduledSub()

    Debug.Print "TheScheduledSub() has run at " & Time

End Sub
```

`Scheduler()` will execute `TheScheduledSub()` at the exact time specified inside `Scheduler()`, defined by **`TimeValue`**.  You can read more about `TimeValue` [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/timevalue-HP005209316.aspx).

You could probably pass the time value you want the Scheduler() sub to execute your sub(s) or function(s) in as a parameter in the sub.

You could probably run a sub 5 hours from now, lets say.  I.E. 
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("05:00:00"), "TheScheduledSub"

or maybe a day from now?   Play around with it.

I did get two subs to execute at different times.  I also tried to execute two at the same time.  My experience with two different subs executing at the same time was that the second sub seemed to execute before the first, but I havent fully explored it.  So YMMV.

I do not think that Excel VBA is multithread capable so keep that in mind. I am running the 32-bit Excel 2010 from the Office suite.  Not sure how the 64-bit Office Excel behaves or for that matter any other version or platform.  Anyway, multithreading / multitasking Excel VBA is not what you asked but it is to be considered.

Seeing this question and playing with the above I can think of a few ideas I want to try myself!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to lower the security level of excel in order to avoid this pop up when launching excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use workbook open and call macro. Just have scheduled tasks open the workbook and the macro will run when workbook is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I found it's a good idea to have

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

at the beginning to disable any popup message that could interrupt your macro when running.

Or see tutorial video: 
http://youtu.be/lFSgV2gym9g